# Automatically append data-labels based content of <th> to corresponding <td> for responsive table view

Tags: javascript, responsive, css-tables

I need to automatically append `data-*` labels to `td`'s based on the content of their corresponding `th`. So, the result should something like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="bg-gray-100">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
      <th>Heading 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Heading 1">table cell content</td>
      <td data-label="Heading 2">table cell content</td>
      <td data-label="Heading 3">table cell content</td>
      <td data-label="Heading 4">table cell content</td>
      <td data-label="Heading 5">table cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

While there are a number of jQuery solutions floating around, I need to accomplish this with vanilla JavaScript

For representative jQuery solutions, see:
1. [How can I copy the corresponding table header (th) to their table cell (td)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320100/how-can-i-copy-the-corresponding-table-header-th-to-their-table-cell-td)

2. [Pull th content into a td data-label attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101366/pull-th-content-into-a-td-data-label-attribute)
3. https://j.eremy.net/responsive-table/)

I would love for the solution to use `element.cellIndex`, but can't seem to make it work.

I've made various wrong-headed attempts.

This is my latest failed attempt:

```
function addMobileTableData() {
  var table = document.querySelector('.table');
  var th = table.querySelectorAll('th');
  var td = table.querySelectorAll('td');
  var tdCollection = Array.from(td);
  var thCollection = Array.from(th);
  var thCount = th.length;
  tdCollection.forEach(function(tdItem, index){
    for (index = 0; index < thCount; index++) {
      var headerLabel = thCollection[index].innerHTML;
      console.log(headerLabel);
      tdItem.setAttribute('data-th', headerLabel[index]);
    };
  });
};
```

It's obviously incorrect. It assigns a `data-th` label to each `td` but appends only the first character in the last string to each `td`.

Hints appreciated if you're in a rush. An explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be great. A full working solution would be Fan-Freaking-Tastic.

But, I'll take what I can get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close actually. Turns out you were accessing the string of the Header label you had returned, hence why only the first character was being returned. Also the extra loop is unnecessary. Working code snippet below:

```js
function addMobileTableData() {
  var table = document.querySelector('.table');
  var bodyTrCollection = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
  var th = table.querySelectorAll('th');
  var thCollection = Array.from(th);

  for (var i = 0; i < bodyTrCollection.length; i++) {
    var td = bodyTrCollection[i].querySelectorAll('td');
    var tdCollection = Array.from(td);
    for (var j = 0; j < tdCollection.length; j++) {
      if (j === thCollection.length) {
        continue;
      }
      var headerLabel = thCollection[j].innerHTML;
      tdCollection[j].setAttribute('data-th', headerLabel);
    }
  }
};
addMobileTableData();
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="bg-gray-100">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
      <th>Heading 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
      <td>table cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: added an extra check to account for the scenario when the number of th and tds don't match.

Second Edit: The function broke down with multiple rows. I have fixed this mistake now.

Comment: Nice! That definitely successfully appends the data-label. There's a small issue, though. I get a console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. It's like the loop is running to many times or something. Not sure.

Comment: Yes you have one td unaccounted for. 4 table headers only 5 td below. My code snipped already has it removed which might have confused you. My bad.

Comment: @DonkeyShame I have edited my response to add an extra check preventing an error from occurring when the number of headers and cells don't match.

Comment: Hmm. Very good point. But even with an equal number of `th` and `td` elements (my real code has six `th`'s and six corresponding `td`'s--I double then triple checked), I still seem to get the error.

Comment: @DonkeyShame Does the extra check solve the problem? See my updated answer

Comment: I certainly wish it did, but it doesn't appear to. Thank you for your patience and insight, @etarhan. I'm looking to quadruple check that I haven't missed an obvious error in my code, but as of now, still getting the error. 

I'll post back shortly after I make sure I'm not screwing something up.

Comment: how we can do for multiple tables on one page?  It appends only for the first table.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise version can be:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table.table');
const headerCells = table.querySelectorAll('thead th');

headerCells.forEach((_headerCell, i) => {
  table
    .querySelectorAll(`tbody tr td:nth-child(${i + 1})`)
    .forEach((cell) => {
      cell.dataset.label = headerCells[i].innerText.trim();
    });
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="bg-gray-100">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
      <th>Heading 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell content</td>
      <td>cell content</td>
      <td>cell content</td>
      <td>cell content</td>
      <td>cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```